# Do I have to create some dummy hardcoded array with data for viewing prefs in table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, preferences, nsuserdefaults

How to create a UITableViewController that displays some hardcoded data in grouped styled (like iPhone settings). For example I need to show some menu options in a table with group style. Now, I know to work with tables and have done it already. But I'm not sure about how should I deal with data that table view will read for constructing the table. Those rows just present some menu options like "order", "review", "about us" then IMHO I have to create some array with that data and store in NSUserDefaults. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plist file of your data.  It can include arrays of items for each group.  Included the plist in your project and read it in for use by your datasource.  That creates a nice decoupling of data from UI.

Comment: If some cells will contain more that a text, for example contain UIButtons, is it possible to store them in plist file too?

Comment: yes. for example you could have a dictionary for each table row and have an array of data in that dictionary for the table row data and other arrays for other objects relating to that row - all within the one dictionary for that row.

Comment: OK but how am I supposed to save that button into plist file. It's just a XML file, I mean, if I opne plist file with xcode am able to enter only text and number into it.

Comment: Save the button information such as the name, create the buttons as needed, probably in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.