# Is it possible to store UIButton in plist file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, plist, uitableview

I need to read some preferences as menu items from plist file, and display them in table view. Is it possible to store some predefined UIButton with IBAction inside plist file? I need to show a table view with meniu like options in home screen. Most of those items are just links to other UIViewControllers but there are several cells that contain UIButtons for opening another screen.

Comment: duplicate post, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192691/do-i-have-to-create-some-dummy-hardcoded-array-with-data-for-viewing-prefs-in-tab

Comment: Why you want to do with plist?

Comment: a plist is xml - why wouldn't you store data in xml format if there isn't much of it, it won't change and it's easy to do so?

Comment: I need to implement a design where table view shows 5 rows in home screen. 4 rows are just text and link to other screens. And one cell contains both text and buttons. Navigation from that row should be done via those buttons. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most any type of data can be represented in a plist. I have stored entire apps as a list of objects (navcontrollers, viewcontrollers, views of different types etc.) all within plists. then created all the objects at runtime based upon the plist data (no nibs used).

Comment: I have entire objects stored in plist data. the top dictionary is a container which contains strings specifying all the properties and the object type. your code first looks at the object type and creates the correct type of object.

Comment: OK but how to store an object? Is it possible to enter it using xcode or do I need to do that programaticaly?

Comment: Look into serialization or create your own plist and store object representation in dictionary (which executes faster):   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/serializations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000947-BCIEBEGI   "The NSSerializer class stores the property list representation in an NSData object that can be written to a file or transmitted to another process or machine"

Answer (score 0):

Hard code the IBActions in your program. Wherever your preferences are set, have each option be a `Boolean` datatype that is directly related to a specific IBAction.

Then, when you're populating  the menu items for the table view, have it convert the plist to an `NSDictionary` with something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *menuPrefs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
bool value;v
value = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"value"] boolValue];

[menuPrefs release];
```

Then simply check the bool values and if they are true add them, if they are not ignore em. Tada. Problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

I dont think this will be possible as there are only predefined datatypes in plist so this will not be possible for plist

Comment: Hello ade, You can only set the property values of the controls and not the controls.... I mean that you can save name, height, width, etc property of UIButton but you cant store whole UIButton.. If you say it is possible .. I would like to go through that again....